# Contact phone numbers Lync SDK 2013

Tags: list, sdk, numbers, contacts, lync

Hello                                                                               I'm using Lync SDK 2013, to display number phones from contact in ListBox, and use the Items (phone number) to call this number by my API.                                So i did a WPF application, that contains just a ListBox, and 2 buttons (Call - Hang up). My apllication is added as custom command in Lync, in RightClick in the contact. and it doesn't have any Lync Controls. So what i want to do is: if i Right Click on the contact, my application launches and gives me the number phone List in the ListBox.                                                                I did it with a WPF that contains the controls: ContactSearchInputBox (to search a contact) and ContactSearchResultList and it works very Well, I don't know how to do it without controls.
Any One Can Help Me !!!! :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public partial class ChoosePhoneNumber : Window
    {
        LyncClient lync_client;
        Contact contact;
        ContactSubscription contact_subscription;
        List<ContactInformationType> contact_information_list;
        ContactManager contact_manager;

        public ChoosePhoneNumber()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            connect_lync();
            get_subscribed_contact(this.contact);
        }
    }
        private void connect_lync()
        {
            try
            {
                lync_client = LyncClient.GetClient();
                contact_manager = lync_client.ContactManager;
            }
            catch (ClientNotFoundException)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Client is ot running", "Error While GetClient", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);
            }
        }

        private void get_subscribed_contact(Contact contact)
        {
            List<object> contact_phone_numbers_list = new List<object>();
            contact_information_list = new List<ContactInformationType>();
            contact_information_list.Add(ContactInformationType.ContactEndpoints);
            contact_information_list.Add(ContactInformationType.DisplayName);

            contact = contact_manager.GetContactByUri("number"); // I put here the number phone of a contact in my list
            contact_subscription = LyncClient.GetClient().ContactManager.CreateSubscription();
            contact_subscription.AddContact(contact);
            contact.ContactInformationChanged += Contact_ContactInformationChanged;
            contact_subscription.Subscribe(ContactSubscriptionRefreshRate.High, contact_information_list);

            List<object> endpoints = (List<object>)contact.GetContactInformation(ContactInformationType.ContactEndpoints);

            var phone_numbers_list = endpoints.Where<object>(N => ((ContactEndpoint)N).Type == ContactEndpointType.HomePhone ||
            ((ContactEndpoint)N).Type == ContactEndpointType.MobilePhone || ((ContactEndpoint)N).Type == ContactEndpointType.OtherPhone
            || ((ContactEndpoint)N).Type == ContactEndpointType.WorkPhone).ToList<object>();
            var name = contact.GetContactInformation(ContactInformationType.DisplayName);

            if (phone_numbers_list != null)
            {
                foreach (var phone_number in phone_numbers_list)
                {
                    contact_phone_numbers_list.Add(((ContactEndpoint)phone_number).DisplayName);
                }
                conboboxPhoneNumbers.ItemsSource = contact_phone_numbers_list;
            }
        }

        private void Contact_ContactInformationChanged(object sender, ContactInformationChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            var contact = (Contact)sender;
            if (e.ChangedContactInformation.Contains(ContactInformationType.ContactEndpoints))
            {
                update_endpoints(contact);
            }
        }

        private void update_endpoints(Contact contact)
        {
            if ((lync_client != null) && (lync_client.State == ClientState.SignedIn))
            {
                ContactEndpoint endpoints = (ContactEndpoint)contact.GetContactInformation(ContactInformationType.ContactEndpoints);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to read and understand the Lync SDK 2013 [Lync Contact](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/jj937302.aspx) documentation.

If you wish to "simulate" the Lync Contact "search" (as per the Client search) then you need to look into the [search API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj933159.aspx).

The other concepts you need to understand is the results returned from all the API are NOT guaranteed to return all the Lync Contact data that asked for.

There is no way with the Lync SDK to "load" all the contact information which is what most people seem to not understand.

The results returned are what the local cache has and no more.  To get the all the Lync Contact information you need to understand the [ContactSubscription](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.lync.model.contactsubscription_di_3_uc_ocs14mreflyncwpf.aspx) model.

For each Lync Contact that you wish to be notified of field updates (or loads) you "subscribe" to the Lync Contact and then you will be notified via the [Contact.ContactInformationChanged](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.lync.model.contact.contactinformationchanged_di_3_uc_ocs14mreflyncwpf.aspx) event.

So your UI must to able to auto-update the information as the fields get loaded / updated from any initial value returned from any Lync [Contact](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.lync.model.contact_di_3_uc_ocs14mreflyncwpf.aspx) value.

Comment: it seems too complicated to what I imagined, and i didn't find a concrete example :(  I read the documentations .. if you have any examplei'm taking. Thanks again for your answer

Comment: There is no example that I know of, but I have done all the above multiple times.  It's most likely better that you just try it and then ask specific questions when you run into problems.

Comment: So I took all my time reading the documentation, there is my code, that search a contact by his Uri (phone number). so my subscription is just for this contact, and i can return just his numbers phone list. but what i want to do, this Uri must be taken when i select a contact, and launch my application (Right Click). I think i must use BeginSearch and not GetContactByUri ??

Comment: My code is published as anwser (too long to be done in comment)

Comment: The code looks ok.  I'm still not sure what your actual question is.  If you have a valid skype URI then GetContactByUri is the best.  If you don't have a URI then BeginSearch is the best so long as you understand you may get more than one result and for phone numbers you will get a generated result.

Comment: If you asking how to get a URI from a "right click" application extension from the Lync client?  So you are talking about the contact-id from: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj945535.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: Exactly, i added the default userId and contactId in my registry, and i don't know how to use it as parameter in GetContactByUri (I ask if it's possible to do). I looked at this example [link](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/993654/Lync-Addin-Send-SMS )but it seems to me something not correct in the OnStartup method added in the Apps.xaml.cs

Comment: I did it, and it works perfectly. i make my App.xaml.cs as answer

Answer (score 0):

```
public partial class App : Application
    {
        protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
        {
            App.Current.DispatcherUnhandledException += Current_DispatcherUnhandledException; ;
            try
            {
                string argsParam = "Contacts=";

                if (e.Args.Length > 1)
                {
                    if (e.Args[2].Contains(argsParam))
                    {
                        var contacts_sip_uri = e.Args[2].Split('<', '>')[1];
                        Params.contacts = contacts_sip_uri;
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Reading Startup Arguments Error - " + ex.Message);
            }

        }

        private void Current_DispatcherUnhandledException(object sender, System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherUnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
        {
            string message = e.Exception.Message;

            if (e.Exception.InnerException != null)
            {
                message += string.Format("{0}Inner Exception: {1}", Environment.NewLine, e.Exception.InnerException.Message);
            }
            MessageBox.Show(message, "Unhandled Exception", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);
        }

    }
```

Params is a public static class that contains just contact as public static string contacts { get; set; }

```
public static class ParamContact
    {
        public static string contacts { get; set; }
    }
```